# Get yarn ressource manager hostname through bash

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to find the yarn resource manager hostname among the differents nodes through bash. The only way I found it is to type any yarn command and grep/awk to get it(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). example:

```
yarn node -list -all
INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/03/18 14:28:16 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/10.100.x.y:8050
Total Nodes:4
a
b
c
d
```

Is there any other way to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

> hdfs getconf -confKey

Example:

> hdfs getconf -confKey yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address.rm212